# STS Upgade - sh: func: command not found - azure

Tags: spring-tool-suite, azure-spring-boot

I am currently working on azure spring. I have recently updated my `Spring Tool Suite` to `Version: 4.21.1.RELEASE` and installed `Azure Toolkit for Eclipse 3.32.0` from the marketplace. After that, I have started getting the following error when I run `mvn package azure-functions:run` from STS.

```
sh: func: command not found
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Azure Functions Core Tools not found. Please go to https://aka.ms/azfunc-install to install Azure Functions Core Tools first.
```

The following command is working fine.

```
my-project % func --version
4.0.5530
```

Also, the command `mvn package azure-functions:run` works from the command line.

```
 my-project % mvn package azure-functions:run
 [INFO] Scanning for projects...
 [INFO] 
 ...
```

Do we need to set some environment variable for this `func` to make it work in STS?

Answer (score 1):

When launching Eclipse from the dock on a Mac, some environment variables, such as PATH, may not be properly set. As a result, the Azure Toolkit may not be able to locate the function core tools needed to launch a function project. We are working on the fix for this issue, please track the status in https://github.com/microsoft/azure-tools-for-java/issues/8225

As a workaround, you may run Spring Tool Suite from bash with `open -a SpringToolSuite4.app`, which should resolve this issue.